# Ensuring Users are Authenticated in Java Web App

Tags: java, security, jsp, servlets, web-applications

My web app has a secure area which users log in to via a JSP.  The JSP posts the user name and password to a servlet, which then checks to see if the users credentials are valid.  If they are valid then the user is directed to the secure resource.  How can I ensure that users can't just navigate to the secure resource without validating first?

Comment: I take it that declarative authentication is not an option for the app (container-managed authentication via the deployment descriptor).

Answer (score 6):

A common approach is to set a token in the user's session i.e.,

`session.setAttribute("loggedIn", "true");`

or even

`session.setAttribute("loggedInUser", "someUserName");`

and check that on any page that should be secured. A good strategy is to perform the check using a servlet filter that you attach to any page to be secured. If they don't pass the check, the filter can redirect to the login page. Also see here: http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html

This is a good article on using filters for authentication also: http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3467801

Comment: Why would this approach be better than container managed authentication?

Comment: It depends on your needs. For a simple application, this is easier, but cma is a good robust solution for more advanced needs. As always, your mileage may vary.

Comment: I would prefer something like, 
session.setAttribute("user", userBean);
Of course with no sensitive information.

Answer (score 4):

What bout using the security-contraint in your web.xml :

```
<security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>Secure</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
```

Comment: See, for example, this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344474/form-authentication-on-website

Answer (score 0):

Make sure people always access your app through a single servlet, where the servlet dispataches the request to a JSP, and returns the resulting response to the browser. This way you will always be in control of what happens because there is a single entry point.

A different approach is to have a session variable (server side, or even in a cookie) which gets checked by each and every JSP which requires authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Security is really hard to get right. Much more than you would usually think. The use of a framework ([Acegi](http://www.acegisecurity.org/) comes to mind), or the standard "" section of web.xml as [LenW pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348090/ensuring-users-are-authenticated-in-java-web-app#349287) is a must ! At least use a filter to handle the authorization part of your security.

I dont really like the solution of using a single point of entry (as [suggested by Rolf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348090/ensuring-users-are-authenticated-in-java-web-app#348137)). It seems to me like an artificial constraint put on your architecture. And there is a lot of good reasons to have multiple servlet in a webapp.

Whatever you do, dont use a technique where you rely on manual code on every page (like : every JSP begining with "if user_authentified ..."). You will forget to put it somewhere ...