# Configuring container-based authentication with alternative digest methods

Tags: java, security, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss

Following up on a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765222/looking-for-a-simple-secure-session-design-with-servlets-and-jsp), I'm trying to figure out how to set up container-based authentication for a J2EE application. Specifically, I need to be able to apply a password digest algorithm other than the ones supported by the `java.security.MessageDigest` (which are SHA, MD2, or MD5 - [here's where I think that limitation is documented](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#Digested%20Passwords)). In this case my database stores Blowfish-encrypted passwords.

I already have the Java code written to get the encrypted password from my database, and compare the user-entered password with the database one by performing the Blowfish encryption. How do I set it up so that the container just uses my own Java class(es) to perform user authentication?

I'm using JBoss AS 5.1 (which I think means my Tomcat version is 6).

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to write a [custom LoginModule](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/CreatingACustomLoginModule) for JBoss.

In your case it should be trivial as all you want to do is to change how password gets encoded so you'll just extend the `DatabaseServerLoginModule` and override a single method like the example in the above link shows.

If you were to do it for a standalone Tomcat, you'd have to write [your own Realm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html). Again, reasonably straightforward as you can extend JDBC or Data Source realm

Comment: Can I do it without changing conf/login-config.xml? It's really ugly to have the select written into that file, especially when I already have some very nice Java code (EJB3 + a POJO) that grabs the user info.

Comment: You can certainly implement `LoginModule` by yourself instead of extending `DatabaseServerLoginModule` and retrieve user info however you want. I'm not sure whether EJB is going to be accessible from LoginModule, though - but it's been a (long) while since I've worked with JBoss; that may have changed.

Comment: Given the difficulty in finding usable documentation on any of this, I'll stick with extending DatabaseServerLoginModule for now. Do you have any links about what the `rolesQuery` module option should contain? I don't have a database table containing any "role" data so I'm lost as to how to handle this. I tried returning a constant string equal to the security-role defined in my DD, and I also tried omitting the line completely, but either way logging in throws an IOException: `No properties file: users.properties or defaults: defaultUsers.properties found`.

Comment: This is all reasonably well described in JBoss docs. Writing a custom login module: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r3/html/ch8.chapter.html#ch8.custom.sect

You can also take a look at `DatabaseServerLoginModule` source; you should be able to reuse lots of code from there. If you want to hardcode your role to some value (e.g. "role1"), you can define rolesQuery as `SELECT 'role1', 'Roles' FROM dual` (adjust as needed for your DB). The 2nd column must always be 'Roles' and 1st should match the `role-name` within `auth-constraint` in `web.xml`

Answer (score 0):

All the documentation I have been able to find online related to writing a custom login module only pertains to JBoss v4 or earlier. I have not been able to locate a single working example of doing this in JBoss v5.1. It is very frustrating. There are no javadocs for JBoss v5.1 that I can locate on the official JBoss website; in fact, there are no current security documents relating to custom modules at all, anywhere on the net. I have searched through every book I have access to in the Barnes & Noble, still no luck. At this point, we are looking into moving off of JBoss, b/c this lack of documentation is just unprofessional.